# sending emails through gmail smtp server but emails are never recieved

Tags: gmail, smtp

sorry if my problem may seem stupid or simple or if what I'm saying makes no sense but I am no good in this area!

I am trying to email payslips through our Payroll System.

The instructions from the payroll company to set this up is to just fill in the email settings below.
 [image: Email settings]

I have filled in my name, email address, username (gmail email address), Password (which is correct, it doesn’t have any numbers or symbols)
Password Authentication options are:    None
Pop 
Login
Plain
I have tried them all!

Outgoing server Port:
When I try the following ports this is what I get:

Port 25 & 587:

[image: Port 25]

Port: 465
[image]

I’m not sure if they are even sending as both say “All payslips have been sent” when Port 25 & 587 are not connecting.
Either way there is no mail being received.

I have also tried sending it through an Outlook account (with the settings updated) with the same result.

I don’t know if the following information is relevant but just in case:

I have enabled insecure apps and enabled POP and IMAP on the Gmail account if that makes any difference.
When I telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 the connection to host is lost after a few seconds.

I have been looking for solutions for the past few days but can’t get anything to work.

Comment: Do you have two factor authentication? Can your firewall be blocking this ports?

Comment: No two factor authentication. I assumed that port 25 and 587 are blocked because when i telnet them the connection fails but 465 connects for a few seconds so I though it was not blocked...is that wrong :/

Comment: Log into the google account `gmail.com` then click your profile on the top right, then choose `my account`. Next click `connected apps and sites`, scroll to bottom and enable `less secure apps: ON`. You cannot send anything with your google creds without this being on.

Comment: I've done that!(I mentioned above that I have enabled insecure apps instead of less secure apps!Oops)